# How would a db be designed to accept reservations everyday except holidays?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

Hope the titel of my question makes sense.

We are building reservations app.

The key stumbling block right now is how to handle reservation dates.

For instance, accordding to their specs, users can make reservations everyday except during holidays.

So, if a user makes a reservation for say, 11/20/2014, if that date is available, it is presented to user for booking.

If that date is not avaialble, the next 30 available dates are presented to the user to choose from.

I have the code to do this check but my question, how do I include the date information that users can compare to the the date they selected?

Sorry guys because I am using an old browser? it won't allow me to add my comments.

So, I am adding it here.

I am just trying to clarify that what I am confused about is how to handle dates that need to be stored on the database.

For instance, whatever date a user selected as preferred event date will need to be compared to the date on our database to see if that date is available for the event.

Where and how should I store that date on the database?

Answer (score 0):

One option might be a secondary table with blackout dates.  Outer join to this table and then check if a date returns that is within the range of dates being requested.  No joined data, then clear to book.